# Error: INVALID_TOKEN: Could not parse auth token

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I writing a protractor e2e test and in my test i generate a firebase token which i pass as a query parameter in the url e.g. browser.get('/login?token=' + token). When the test navigates to the login page, i use the firebase authwithcustomtoken to try to authenticate the user. e.g.

```
Refs.rootRef.authWithCustomToken($location.search().token, function (err, authData) {
   console.log(err, authData);
});
```

Everytime the code above runs i keep getting this error 'Error: INVALID_TOKEN: Could not parse auth token'.This is the code i use to generate the token in node.js before passing it to the browser as a query string:

```
var secret = 'XXXXXXX';
var tokenGenerator = new FirebaseTokenGenerator(secret);
var token = tokenGenerator.createToken(
  {
    uid: 'google:uid', 
    email: 'xxx.xxx@xxx.co'
  }
);
```

Before i started using the node firebasetokengenerator package, i used to generate the token on this site http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/D4YL8/light/. I would then test on this site to see if firebase authenticates the token i just created and it always works but as soon as i use the token in my test i would get the error could not parse auth token. I then tried using the firebasetokengenerator node module and i am still getting the same error message. I don't know what the problem is.

I would appreciate if someone could help me out on this. Thanks

Comment: Could you share some version info? This is likely a Firebase version incompatibility.

Comment: @kato my firebase version is 2.0.5

Comment: @kato i upgraded my firebase to 2.0.6 which is the latest version and i am still getting the same invalid token error

Comment: And which version of the node tokengen are you using? Which version of node? More details would be better than terse replies here.

Comment: @kato firebasetoken generator is using version 2.0.0 and node version is 0.10.33

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this.